# How to use Sendgrid Parse API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, parsing, post, sendgrid

How do I configure the application to receive the emails coming to the server.

I have a rails application which is readily sending the emails to email id's as I assign, but I don't know what to write in my controller to get the emails objects(headers, footers, body, etc) from parse api.

I am new to rails, So I wish to create a basic topic where experienced people should gather and reply to make the sendgrid api more and more informable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you already have your MX records configured and you've [set up the parse settings in the SendGrid backend](http://sendgrid.com/developer/reply).  This is what it would look like from a code perspective:

#### 1. Add a route to your `config/routes.rb`

You'll need to define a route that will accept the messages.

```
# /inbound
match '/inbound' => 'messages#inbound', :via => :post
```

#### 2. Configure your method to return a 200 response code

In my example this is file would be `app/controllers/messages_controller.rb`.  All I'll do is log the params, but you should replace that bit with your own logic.  The important part is that I'm returning a `200` response code.

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def inbound
    puts "*"
    puts params
    puts "*"

    render :json => { "message" => "OK" }, :status => 200
  end
end
```

---

The result of the above code will be logging something along these lines to your rails server output:

```
**************************************************
{
        "headers" => "Received: by 127.0.0.1 with SMTP ..."
    "attachments" => "0",
           "dkim" => "{@sendgrid.com : pass}",
        "subject" => "Hello world",
             "to" => "foo@snailgrid.com",
           "html" => "<div>... </div>",
           "from" => "Swift <swift@sendgrid.com>",
           "text" => "Some text body",
       "envelope" => "{\"to\":[\"foo@snailgrid.com\"],\"from\":\"mike.swift@sendgrid.com\"}",
            "SPF" => "pass",
     "controller" => "messages",
         "action" => "inbound"
}
**************************************************
```

Comment: Well thanks for the exact code. I wanna ask one thing, how to configure that url, I mean if i have to test it at my localhost then what should the URL be, although the mx records part is done already but URL has to be decided by me. Shall I paste the controller...

Comment: Use localtunnel for local testing (http://progrium.com/localtunnel/).  For my example, I have a domain (snailgrid.com) that has MX records pointing at SendGrid.  On the sendgrid backend, I have a parse record for 'snailgrid.com' pointing to my localtunnel domain.

Comment: And if you could mark this as the correct answer so people don't get confused, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's working man, I can see every email sent on my terminal log...
But how to seperate the body, to, from, etc...
I mean, are there some tutorials you can refer for that..??

Comment: Moreover they are dynamic, I mean, hash comes in when an email is sent... How do I capture that..??

Comment: You would access them through the `params` hash.  So `params[:to]` in my example would be `foo@snailgrid.com`, `params[:from]` would be `Swift <swift@sendgrid.com>`, etc.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Exactly... That was what i was loking for...(sry for asking baby-questions, but I am learning, and u are a great help)

Comment: No problem. Happy to help however I can

Comment: how do we forward attachments...??
i.e. if we have attachments in the mail recieved... does sendgrid support attachments also in newsletters..??

Comment: You can just attach them the same way you would attach any file with ActionMailer http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-attachments